# How can I make legend error bars horizontal in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make a graph with matplotlib where the error bars in the graph are vertical,
but the error bar in legend is horizontal.  The example code (below) produces a
graph where the error bar in the legend is vertical.
How can I make the legend error bar horizontal?

code:

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 6)  
y = np.sin(x)  
dy = 0.1*np.abs(y)  
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr = dy, label="data", fmt='o')  
plt.legend(loc="upperright", numpoints=1, frameon=False)  
plt.show()
```

In the produced graph, I want the error bar inside the legend to be horizontal, while the error bars in the rest of the graph remain vertical.  I want this so that the error bar in the legend is not confused for a data point.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Which one is your main question? You should post each question as indiviuials.

Comment: The easiest way to not confuse the data point is just to keep the legend frame on....

Comment: See http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html  It is not as strait forward as it should be, but you can register arbitrary handlers for artist classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the error bar line object from the default legend and then create a custom legend with it and it will automatically be drawn horizontally, like this:

```
import numpy as np                 # v 1.19.2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    # v 3.3.2

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 6)  
y = np.sin(x)  
dy = 0.1*np.abs(y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=dy, label='data', fmt='o', ecolor='red')

# Retrieve handles and labels: note the tuple within the tuple to
# unpack the handles
(errorbar_container,), labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
point, line = errorbar_container.get_children()

# Create the custom legend: note that the handles are drawn on top of
# one another in the order that they are listed in the tuple
plt.legend([(line, point)], labels, frameon=False)

plt.show()
```

[image: legend_errorbar_horizontal]