# Error bars in 1 direction but direction varies from point to point

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

I have a dataset plotted using `plt.scatter(x,y)` and an array of individual errors `yerr` and `xerr` that I want to put on each point as error bars using `plt.errorbar(x,y,xerr,yerr, fmt='none')`.

As some values in `xerr` and `yerr` are positive, but some are negative I only want the error bar to go in the `+ve` or `-ve` direction according to this but when I use this code, it automatically plots in both directions.

How can I get it to just plot in a single, variable direction based on if the error array value is `+ve` or `-ve`?

I can think of a way to do it by creating new arrays to plot positive and negative directions but surely there's a quicker, easier way...

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! I encourage you to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we may help you find a solution that works for your particular problem. It should ideally contain a [small sample of data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/14148248) and some code showing what you have tried. It should be possible to copy-paste it and run it without any extra effort, as illustrated in the answers I have posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65579573/14148248) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66198319/14148248).

Comment: Have you tried using `uplims` and `lolims` as shown in [this example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/errorbar_limits.html)?

Answer (score 0):

When providing one array for the x-errors, they are interpreted as symmetrical errors. To have different error bars left and right, a tuple of two arrays can be given: one array with `maximum(0, -xerr)` and one with `maximum(0, xerr)`. Note that these values are supposed to be positive. The y-errors work similarly.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.random.uniform(1, 50, size=(2, 20))
xerr, yerr = np.random.uniform(-4, 4, size=(2, 20))
plt.errorbar(x, y,
             xerr=(np.maximum(0, -xerr), np.maximum(0, xerr)),
             yerr=(np.maximum(0, -yerr), np.maximum(0, yerr)),
             fmt='none', color='navy')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Here is an example with x and y on a grid:

```py
x = np.tile(np.arange(10, 160, 10), 10)
y = np.repeat(np.arange(10, 110, 10), 15)
xerr, yerr = np.random.uniform(-4, 4, size=(2, len(x)))
plt.errorbar(x, y,
             xerr=(np.maximum(0, -xerr), np.maximum(0, xerr)),
             yerr=(np.maximum(0, -yerr), np.maximum(0, yerr)),
             fmt='none', color='navy')
plt.show()
```

[image: x and y on grid]

PS: The same plot can also be generated via short horizontal and vertical lines, calling `plt.hlines()` and `plt.vlines()`:

```py
plt.hlines(y, x, x+xerr, color='navy')
plt.vlines(x, y, y+yerr, color='navy')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?